# Orchard CMS - How to specify the call order of content handlers?

Tags: call, orchardcms, autofac, handlers

Content handlers resolved by Autofac are returned in an unpredicatable order. I need some content handlers to be invoked in a specific order.

Example:

**Feature A**

Content handler A -> assigns / removes role X from a user content item

**Feature B**

Content handler B -> evaluates assigned roles and when role X is found it and takes further actions

As you see, in my case it makes no sense to call handler B before A as role X must be updated in A before B can even execute further actions based on the role X assignment.

Currently Autofac resolves the handlers in an ordering as follows

```
..., A, B, ...
```

but the handlers are stored in the handler list in the following order

```
... B, A, ...
```

Then Orchard invokes the handlers like

```
Handlers.Invoke(handler => ..., Logger);
```

which obviously calls the handlers in the order

```
... B, A, ...
```

Is there anything i can do to ensure a specific order?

Here is a discussion in google groups about a similar issue:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autofac/HE66utFpvkg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never rely on the order of content handlers. If you need to run code in a specific order then you can define your own handler interface with a property for ordering your handlers. For example:

```
public interface IMyHandler {
    int Priority { get; }
    void Invoke(ContentItem item);
}
```

You can register this interface with a custom Autofac module inside your Orchard module. Then inside a regular content handler you can inject `IEnumerable<IMyHandler>`. This will provide you with all registered handlers of `IMyHandler` type. Then you can order them by `Priority` and call them in a foreach loop.

```
foreach (var handler in _myHandlers.OrderBy(x => x.Priority)) {
    handler.Invoke(item);
}
```